# c# removing commas

Tags: c#

How to remove unnecessary comma's in string?

e.g

```
textbox.text = "1,23,45,67";
```

What I want is, to remove second and third comma and next one if appears,
e.g

```
textbox.text = "1,234567";
```

Or in other way, how to allowed to place only one comma?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This one is working like you expected (don't forget to add `using System.Linq;`):

```
string[] Splitted = textbox.Text.Split(',');
textbox.Text = string.Join(",", Splitted.Take(2)) + string.Join("", Splitted.Skip(2));
```

> 123 **->** 123
>
> 123,123 **->** 123,123
>
> 123,123,123 **->** 123,123123

Answer (score 0):

here you can use string trim method, and you can see more detailed info over here:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d4tt83f9(v=vs.110).aspx